# How do I use if function from python file in my kv file using KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm doing a signup screen and I'm trying to get a button to switch screens if certain conditions for the inputs are met. I created an if function in my python file that's in the Screen class where my button is.

Some of the conditions use other functions I've made - checkNumAl() and checkAl(), which checks if there is at least one number and letter or at least one letter. These do not work in my kv file which is why I've made the if function in my python file.

Now I don't know how to get my button in my kv file to check a condition in my python function, or more like I don't know how to flag that the conditions are met.

Python code:

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '321')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '657')
import kivy
import kivymd
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import re
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


def checkNumAl(str):
    flag_a = False
    flag_b = False
    for i in str:
        if i.isalpha():
            flag_a = True
        if i.isdigit():
            flag_b = True
    return flag_a and flag_b

def checkAl(str):
    flag_a = False
    for i in str:
        if i.isalpha():
            flag_a = True
    return flag_a

class SignupWindow(Screen):
    age = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    password_c = ObjectProperty(None)
    signup_submit = ObjectProperty(None)
    icon = StringProperty()


    def submit(self):
        while True:
            if self.email.text != "" and self.email.text.count("@") == 1 and self.email.text.count(".") > 0 and 20 > len(self.username.text) > 2 and re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$", self.username.text) and checkAl(self.username.text) == True:
                if self.password.text == self.password_c.text and len(self.password.text) > 5 and checkNumAl(self.password.text) == True:
                    return True
                else:
                     return False
            else:
                return False



class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyMainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
        return kv



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
WindowManager:

    SignupWindow:
    MainWindow:
    LoginWindow:


<Label>:

    font_size: 40
    color: 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 1
    size_hint: 0.8, 0.1

<Form@MDTextField>:

    font_size: 30
    color: 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 1
    size_hint: 0.85, 0.075
    padding_x: 20
    padding_y: [self.height / 1.5 - (self.line_height / 1.5) * len(self._lines), 0]
    multiline: False
    write_tab: False
    mode: 'rectangle'

<IconListItem>

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

<SignupWindow>:

    name: "signup"
    age: age
    email: email
    username: username
    password: password
    password_c: password_c
    signup_submit: signup_submit

    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: 0.2, 0.8, 1, 0.6
        Label:
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "x": 0.1}
            text: "Sign Up"


        Button:
            id: age
            text: "Year"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.17, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.7375, "x": 0.075}
            on_parent: drop_content.dismiss()
            on_release: drop_content.open(self)
        DropDown:
            id: drop_content
            on_select: age.text = f'{args[1]}' # see note below
            Button:
                id: btn1
                size_hint_x: 0.85
                size_hint_y: None
                text: 'First Item'
                height: 35
                on_release: drop_content.select('First Item')
            Button:
                id: btn3
                size_hint_x: 0.85
                size_hint_y: None
                text: 'Second Item'
                height: 35
                on_release: drop_content.select('Third Item')



        Form:
            id: email
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.6375, "x": 0.075}
            hint_text: 'Email'
            on_text_validate: username.focus = True

        Form:
            id: username
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.5375, "x": 0.075}
            hint_text: 'Username'
            on_text_validate: password.focus = True

        Form:
            id: password
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.4375, "x": 0.075}
            hint_text: 'Password'
            password: True
            on_text_validate: password_c.focus = True
            max_text_length: 20
            min_text_length: 6

        MDCheckbox:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "48dp", "48dp"
            pos_hint:{"top": 0.355, "x": 0.83}
            on_active:
                if password.password == True: password.password = False
                else: password.password = True
                if password.password == True: password_text.text = "Show password"
                else: password_text.text = "Hide password"

        MDLabel:
            id: password_text
            text: "Show password"
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.3668, "x": .52}
            font_size: 30

        Form:
            id: password_c
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.3, "x": 0.075}
            hint_text: 'Confirm password'
            password: True

        MDCheckbox:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "48dp", "48dp"
            pos_hint:{"top": 0.2175, "x": 0.83}
            on_active:
                if password_c.password == True: password_c.password = False
                else: password_c.password = True
                if password_c.password == True: password_c_text.text = "Show password"
                else: password_c_text.text = "Hide password"

        MDLabel:
            id: password_c_text
            text: "Show password"
            pos_hint: {"top": .2293, "x": .52}
            font_size: 30

        Button:
            id: signup_submit
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.1375, "x": 0.075}
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint: 0.85, 0.075
            on_release: app.root.current = "login" if root.submit == True else "signup"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    Button:
        text: "Go back"



<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
```

When I run the app works but nothing happens when I click the submit button.
I tried lots of different things but I don't know what to return and set as the condition in my kv file. Also, I'm using KivyMD and I can't do anything with a ScreenManager in my python file.
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Also, bigger problem, [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot the `()` in your call to `submit()`. Try this line in your `kv`:

```
        on_release: app.root.current = "login" if root.submit() else "signup"
```

Comment: It works now! But now when you give the wrong input the app freezes and nothing works. Do I have to make something specific happen when the conditions aren't met?

Comment: Nvm I fixed that too by returning False on else instead of pass